# Correct way to import dependencies with specific naming and classpath requirements?

Tags: java, maven

I am developing a project that has a dependency on a third party library, packaged as a JAR, that has some non-java resources in it.
I do not have access to its sources, but apparently the way the library is obtaining certain resources in it is by means of specifying a URI relative to the JAR of this library.
In other words: the code works only if the library jar has a specific name.

This is giving me lots of headaches since I use Maven to build my project. Normally I install third party libraries in my local repository and import them as dependencies in my POM, and I do not care if the name of the jar in a dependency library was changed or not by Maven (typically adding a version to the name).

What is the correct way to solve this problem ? I have the intuition I should somehow import the third party library with the expected name, and somehow add to the classpath the parent directory where the library jar was imported (so the jar can be found at runtime given its name). Is this correct ? If so how I could do this ?

To complicate things a bit more, the project I am developing is also a library itself, so it is also supposed to be imported by other projects using Maven.
For instance, first I thought about declaring the library as **provided** and then copy it to a file (with the required name) in a directory in my project with something like:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>theGroup</groupId>
                                <artifactId>theArtifact</artifactId>
                                <version>theVersion</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                <destFileName>EXPECTED_NAME.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But this will not work since the copied file is not considered a transitive dependency when importing my library into another project.

**UPDATE:**

I guess something that may work is locating the third party jar in the resources folder (with the expected name) and then somehow adding the jar contents to the classpath in a way that this classpath will also be considered with transitive dependencies. 
In case this solution may work, what is the easiest way to do this ?

Comment: I don't see an easy and reliable way to do this. Any chance to use another library?

Answer (score 0):

You could copy that jar in a folder of your proyect and add the depenece with system scope.

Let's say your jar's name is "particularLib.jar". You could create a folder called external-libs under your main project and copy the jar inside. You could declare the dependency in this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>particular</groupId>
    <artifactId>particularLib</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/external-libs/partucularLib.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```